# Convergence in semi-norms topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Assuming the series of functions $\{\phi_{n}(x)\}$ and the function $\phi(x)$ are in Schwartz space $S(R)$,
now my question is this,

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_{n}(x)\to \phi(x)$ (in Hilbert space $L^2[-\infty,\infty]$)
imply $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{n}(x)\to \phi(x)$ (in semi-norms topology of Schwartz space)?

Comment: In general, $L^2$ convergence will imply pointwise convergence almost everyone with respect to a subsequence.  The convergence of the sequence $\phi_n$ along the seminorm $\phi \mapsto \sup |\phi(x)|$ needs to be uniform.  And I don't know how you would say anything about the convergence of the derivatives.  I doubt the result is true

Comment: Let me ask the question in other way, Lets assume $\phi_{n}(x)\in S(R)$ for $i=1,...,n$, is a discrete orthogonal bases for Hilbert space $L^{2}[-\infty,\infty]$. Now if $\phi(x)\in S(R)$ is expanded according to this bases, e.g. $\phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \phi_{n}(x)$ in $L^2$, does the series converges in semi-norm topology to $\phi(x)$ as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to the follow-up question in the comment: it is *possible* to make a countable projective family of Hilbert spaces $H^k$ whose projective limit is the Schwartz space (further, with Hilbert-Schmidt transition maps), e.g., by completing Schwartz functions (or test functions) with respect to norms $|f|^2_k=\langle (-\Delta+x^2)^k f,f\rangle$. The compactness of the resolvent gives an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions, which are provably in the Schwartz space, and which are *orthogonal* in every $H^k$ (these are Hermite polynomials times a suitable Gaussian).

Then it is true that $f\in H^k$ (with $k\ge 0$) has an expansion in $H^k$, and an expansion in $L^2$. Of course, the expansion in $H^k$ converges in $L^2$, and by uniqueness the coefficients must be the same. (But beware that the norms of the eigenfunctions vary depending on $k$, although they remain orthogonal.)

Thus, for $f\in H^\infty={\mathcal S}$, the $L^2$ expansion does converge in ${\mathcal S}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for.

Comment: @AK1977 Good. Also, a similar (and simpler) phenomenon occurs on the circle, looking at Fourier series, using literal Sobolev norms-squared $\langle (1-\Delta)^k f,f\rangle$. The usual exponentials give an orthogonal basis in every $H^k({\mathrm circle})$, and the usual Sobolev imbedding shows that the proj lim $H^\infty$ is exactly $C^\infty$, and so on.

Comment: I was wondering why you said "these are Hermite polynomials times a suitable Gaussian". Other than this orthogonal base, isn't there any other $L^2$ orthogonal base in Schwartz space?

Comment: For example in ----Mathematics 2015, 3, 527-562; doi:10.3390/math3020527------ the authors just work this out for that base. But is my statement (written in comments) true in general for any $L^2$ base in $S(R)$

Comment: There are many orthogonal bases for $L^2$ consisting of Schwartz functions, but without additional information (of one sort or another), the corresponding $L^2$ expansion for a Schwartz function need not converge to that function in the Schwartz space.

Comment: @AK1977, not quite, I think. The compact resolvent gives a discrete decomposition, but, e.g., with a not-very-smooth confining potential added to the Laplacian, one may fail to have the Schwartz space expressed as a sort of abstracted Sobolev $H^{-\infty}$ space obtained as the projective limit of the completions with respect to $\langle T^k f,f\rangle=|f|_k^2$. For $T=-\Delta+q(x)$ with sufficiently increasing smooth "confining potential", the same conclusion about the Schwartz space being the limit holds, so your desired conclusion (as in comment) does hold.

Comment: For example if   1-  $T$ is continuous map on $S(R)$ implying $q(x)$ is smooth and with all its derivatives are polynomially bonded  2- the resolvent is compact (thus eigenvectors are complete in L^2) 3- eigenvectors in $S(R)$

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not because this would imply ${\scr S}=L^2$ (as $\scr S$ is dense in $L^2$ and complete with its Frechet topology).

Comment: I don't understand this answer because first $S$ is dense in $L^{2}$ with respect to Hilbert topology (not Frechet topology) and second I demand the series in $S$ to converge to an elements of $S$ and not any other member of Hilbert space.

Comment: The condition would imply that the Frechet topology on $\scr S$ coincides with the $L^2$-norm restricted to $\scr S$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see now that it is true for my original question. But how about if we only restrict the matter to specific series coming from expansion in term of a bases in $S$ (My second question written in comments)  ?